# getting awk to print working dir while processing files

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble with this one. I need to get awk to print the working dir for each line processed, lets say in the first column of the output. Here the command I'm using :

```
awk -F, ' FNR==NR {idsA[$1]; next} $1 in idsA ' noms */node.csv
```

I'm processing with this command files in different directories.

here is a sample output :

12,,,-4.8938065
15,,,-3.9248969
16,,,-3.7229307
17,,,-3.5086633
18,,,-3.2806812

What I need :

working_dir,12,,,-4.8938065
working_dir,15,,,-3.9248969
working_dir,16,,,-3.7229307
working_dir,17,,,-3.5086633
working_dir,18,,,-3.2806812

How could I get this done ?

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use awk built in file name variable `$FILENAME`.

i suppose it comes with complete path of the file.

you can try for that and check

Comment: Thanx, works with FILENAME. I'll just remove what I don't need in the complete path. Simple solution... Here's the final command : awk -F, ' FNR==NR {idsA[$1]; next} $1 in idsA {print FILENAME"," $0}' noms */node.csv